# How to write a native query to select only one column from oracle DB through spring data JPA in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, oracle11g

Im writing an api using springboot. I want to write a native query to my oracle db to fetch only one column data from it through jpa repository.

I have already did something like this

This is my repository class

```
@Repository 
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employees, Integer> {

  @Query(value="SELECT city FROM emp", nativeQuery=true) 
  public List<Employees> findAllCity(); 
}
```

This is my service class

```
public List<Employees> getAllCity() { 
  return employeeRepository.findAllCity(); 
}
```

This is my controller class

```
@GetMapping("/getAllCity") 
public List<Employees> getAllCity() { 
  return employeeServices.getAllCity(); 
}
```

This is my model class

```
package com.Slayer.MatTable.model; 
import jakarta.persistence.Column; 
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity 
@Table(name="emp") 
public class Employees { 

  @Id 
  @Column(name="emp_id") 
  private int empId; 
  @Column(name="name")
  private String name; 
  @Column(name="dept") 
  private String dept;
  @Column(name="city")
  private String city; 
  @Column(name="dob") 
  private String dob;

 public int getEmpId() { return empId; } 
public String getName() { return name; }
 public String getDept() { return dept; } 
public String getCity() { return city; } 
public String getDob() { return dob; } 
public void setEmpId(int empId) { this.empId = empId; } 
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; } 
public void setDept(String dept) { this.dept = dept; }
 public void setCity(String city) { this.city = city; } public void setDob(String dob) { this.dob = dob; } }
```

But this is giving me this error.

```
Hibernate: SELECT city FROM emp 
2023-04-12T10:23:59.718+05:30 WARN  8488 [nio-8082-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 17006, SQLState: 99999 
2023-04-12T10:23:59.718+05:30 ERROR 8488 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Invalid column name 
2023-04-12T10:23:59.735+05:30 ERROR 8488 --- [nio-8082-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unable to find column position by name: emp_id] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndexPrimitive(OracleStatement.java:4256 undefined) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:4214 undefined) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
   at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:298 undefined) ~[ojdbc8-21.7.0.0.jar:21.6.0.0.0]
   at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.findColumn(HikariProxyResultSet.java undefined) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
   at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractResultSetAccess.resolveColumnPosition(AbstractResultSetAccess.java:62 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.results.DomainResultCreationStateImpl.resolveSqlExpression(DomainResultCreationStateImpl.java:275 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.resolveSqlSelection(BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.java:266 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.metamodel.mapping.internal.BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.generateFetch(BasicEntityIdentifierMappingImpl.java:377 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.afterInitialize(AbstractEntityResultGraphNode.java:62 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createDomainResult(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1300 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.results.dynamic.DynamicResultBuilderEntityCalculated.buildResult(DynamicResultBuilderEntityCalculated.java:136 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.results.dynamic.DynamicResultBuilderEntityCalculated.buildResult(DynamicResultBuilderEntityCalculated.java:31 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.results.ResultSetMappingImpl.resolve(ResultSetMappingImpl.java:222 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.resolveJdbcValuesSource(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:559 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:350 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.performList(NativeSelectQueryPlanImpl.java:105 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.sql.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:602 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94 undefined) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar:6.1.7.Final]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:127 undefined) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90 undefined) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148 undefined) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136 undefined) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136 undefined) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120 undefined) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164 undefined) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143 undefined) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77 undefined) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123 undefined) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391 undefined) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119 undefined) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137 undefined) ~[spring-tx-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134 undefined) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218 undefined) ~[spring-aop-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy105.findAllCity(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   at com.Slayer.MatTable.service.EmployeeServices.getAllCity(EmployeeServices.java:26 undefined) ~[classes/:na]
   at com.Slayer.MatTable.controller.Controller.getAllCity(Controller.java:34 undefined) ~[classes/:na]
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104 undefined) ~[na:na]
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578 undefined) ~[na:na]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207 undefined) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152 undefined) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:537 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885 undefined) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:631 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:6.0]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201 undefined) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116 undefined) ~[spring-web-6.0.7.jar:6.0.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61 undefined) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.7.jar:10.1.7]
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589 undefined) ~[na:na]
```

I want to pass a native query to my oracle db through jpa to fetch data from only one column in my oracle db

Im using spring boot 3.0.5 with oracle 11g.

I'm sure that there's no connection error between my oracle db and springboot app... Becz other methods are working fine.

Comment: What if you run same query directly to your database does it run successfully ?

Comment: It does @AnandDwivedi

Comment: Can you share Employees class ?

Comment: `Invalid column name` according to your error. So your query appears to be wrong. Another thing you want a list of cities why return a list `Employee` objects and not just `List<String>`?

Comment: I have added my model class now @AnandDwivedi

Comment: Thankyou brother @M.Deinum .... I should have returned String List... Wow such a simple error